# How to import array and function into function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

1. How to import into function an existing function that I have alreqdy created before ?
2. How to import into function an array ?

```
function namarray (arr[])
{}

function namfunc (fun())
{}
```

How to write it in right syntax ?

Comment: The term "absorb into function" does not make sense.

Comment: Explain, what you want to achieve?

Comment: Seems like maybe you're interested in how to pass a reference to a function into another function and a reference to an array into a function?

Comment: Maybe the right word is imoort ?

Comment: Like this: function (name) and than you can send to the function any variable you want when you apply the function on real variable you have created.

Comment: @lir5222 If you have used the right word instead of import, you must have got some answers so far

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz shame on me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the same in both cases, you're passing what you want as an `argument` to the function. With a function, you're just passing the function name, so don't include the `()` - you use that later when you want to invoke the function

You can of course choose to save your inputs to variables inside the function

```js
// 1) How to import into function an existing function that I have alreqdy created before ?
// 2) How to import into function an array ?

function testFunction () {
  return 'I am the test function';
}

function questionOne (input) {
  console.log(input());
}

function questionTwo (input) {
  console.log(`I was given the input ${input}, which is an ${typeof input}`);
}

questionOne(testFunction);
questionTwo([1,2,3]);

// In reply to comment
let longArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,111,222,333];
questionTwo(longArray);
```

Comment: thank you very much. But if the array is very long, can't you just write the array name or something ?

Comment: Yes, Absolutely